# OleDB Destination executes full rollback on error, Bulk Insert Task doesn't

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

I'm using SSIS and BIDS to process a text file who contains lots (millions) of records. I decided to use the Bulk Insert Task and it worked great but then the destination table needed an additional column with a default value on the insert operation and the Bulk Insert Task stopped working. After that, I decided to use a Derived Column with the defaul value and an OleDB Destination to insert the bulk data. It solved my last problem but generated a new one: If there is an error when inserting the data in the OleDB Destination, then it executes a full rollback and no row was added on my table, but when I used the Bulk Insert Task, there were rows based in the BatchSize configuration. Let me explain it with a sample:

- I use a text file with 5000 lines. The file contained a duplicate id (intentionally) between the rows 3000 and 4000.
- Before starting the DTS, the destination table was totally empty.
- Using Bulk Insert Task, after the error raised (and the DTS stopped), the destination table had 3000 rows. I set the *BatchSize* attribute to 1000.
- Using OleDB Destination, after the error raised, the destination table had 0 rows! I set the *Rows per batch* attribute to 1000 and the *Maximum insert commit size* to its max value: 2147483647. I tried changing last one to 0, no effect.

Is this the normal behavior of OleDB Destination? Can someone provide me a guide about working with these tasks? Should I forget to use these tasks and use the [Bulk Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms188365%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) from T-SQL?

As a side note, I also tried following the instructions for `KEEPNULLS` in [Keep Nulls or UseDefault Values During Bulk Import (SQL Server)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187887.aspx) to not use the OleDB Destination task, but it didn't work (maybe is just me).

---

EDIT: Additional info about the problem.

Table structure (sample)

Table T

```
id int, name varchar(50), processed int default 0
```

CSV File (sample)

```
1, hello
2, world
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no rolling back on Bulk Inserts, that's why they are fast.

---

Take a look at using format files:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179250.aspx

Comment: Can you give table structure and a sample of the data that is causing the problem?

Comment: Yes, I've found this link by some research and lot of testing. I managed to do it using the XML format. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially place this in a [transaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137690(v=sql.90)) in SSIS ([you'll need MSDTC running](http://bisherryli.wordpress.com/2011/01/22/transactions-in-sql-server-integration-services-ssis/)), or you could create T-SQL script with a [try-catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41869/is-sql-server-bulk-insert-transactional) to handle any exceptions of the bulk insert (probably just rollback or commit).