# SQL Server losing records?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's a weird one: When running a BULK INSERT to add 20 million or so records to a Table from a huge text file, after it's been running a while there are, say, 2,500,000 rows...I look again in 15 minutes and there are 2,200,000 rows...a little while later there are 2,000,000. How can the number of records be going DOWN during a BULK INSERT? I notice I also got a couple of DISK FULL warnings. Does SQL Server somehow start deleting records when the drive is getting full? Help!

Comment: How much free space is on the drive each time you query? Also, something of a guess, but I'm thinking that things aren't `COMMIT`ted as you may expect. [This question may inspire.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41869/is-sql-server-bulk-insert-transactional)

Answer (score 0):

I would try this in a couple batches of 2 million records and see what happens. I pulled this from [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx):

> **Performance Considerations**
>
> If the number of pages to be flushed in a
>   single batch exceeds an internal threshold, a full scan of the buffer
>   pool might occur to identify which pages to flush when the batch
>   commits. This full scan can hurt bulk-import performance. A likely
>   case of exceeding the internal threshold occurs when a large buffer
>   pool is combined with a slow I/O subsystem. To avoid buffer overflows
>   on large machines, either do not use the TABLOCK hint (which will
>   remove the bulk optimizations) or use a smaller batch size (which
>   preserves the bulk optimizations). Because computers vary, we
>   recommend that you test various batch sizes with your data load to
>   find out what works best for you.

You also may want to look into using the [bcp utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx).

Comment: Hi, dylpickle! Well, this has been working OK generally up to now, always with a LOT of records. I am just wondering if it is acting up because the disk may be getting full. But that still doesn't explain why the number of records is going DOWN as the BULK INSERT keeps running...????!!

Comment: Yea it is strange. I think Bob Kaufman may be onto something with the rollback idea. Disk space and log size is a bit of missing info that could help diagnose.

Comment: SQL server uses threads and job lists. Let's say your bulk thread makes a lot of insert jobs in batches to be processed/written to disk. Then you have another thread that actually writes it to disk, which has to wait for the OS to give it clearance to directly write to disk, then it takes a job and writes it to disk. If an error occurs on the job it throws the error, cleans, exits, and waits for the next writing window, then repeats with the next batch. That's how the jobs keep running in sync, sometimes tripping, never stopping.